# Springboot can't find resources! (Suddenly stopped working)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

So the thing is, since I moved my resources (css, images, js) to **resources/static** folder my stuff started working.

Until I created a new .html page (meant to be dynamic) and pasted in **resources/templates**. Then all my resources (css, images) stopped working (can't be found) and I can't make it work again.

I'm using SpringBoot + Thymeleaf and the code can be found [at GitHub](https://github.com/CayoSouza/Escambo-Livre)

I couldn't manage to find a solution after 3 hours of searching, that's why I'm here. Thank you, hope you guys can help :/

Edit (some images):

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaVFJ.png)

The link:

```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

[What happens (was working before, I didn't change anything in the code of listed images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAwKQ.png)

Comment: I think /resources/static is for web content like CSS, JavaScript, images, etc.  /resources/templates is for Thymeleaf templates.  You need both.

Comment: Yes, I got both. My problem is that after a random event my resources stopped working, like it can't be found by the page anymore.

Comment: Please add the error log.

Comment: There is no error in the log.

Comment: Random event - can't help you there.

Comment: The random event was described: "creation of the .html page", but thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened but after starting deleting/commenting some code I wasn't using anymore I started to get errors and managed to track the next file to "fix" (delete or comment) and after that it worked again.

Looks like something in the application wasn't right and it didn't give me any erros so I had to manually try to find it.

I'll keep updating this thread if I find anything useful related.